# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties when trying to upgrade spring boot version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am developing a sample Spring integration project which has kafka listener using spring integration. This is working fine with lower version of boot (boot - 1.5.9, kafka-client 1.0.0, spring-integration-kafka 2.3.0, spring-kafka 1.3.2). But getting below error while upgrading boot version from 1.5.9 to 2.1.x :-

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:275) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1457) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1384) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

mvn dependency tree :-

```
mvn dependency:tree | find "kafka"
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
```

Please suggest a working pom for boot version 2.1.x or 2.2.x so that it runs without error.
Key artifats that i am using :- kafka-clients, spring-integration-kafka, spring-kafka & spring-boot-starter-integration (All these have their own version provided by boot and not mentioned explicitly except spring-integration-kafka (2.3.0)).

Pom :-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample.report</groupId>
    <artifactId>Report</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Report</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You cannot just upgrade Spring Boot, as that will upgrade spring dependencies and others. You choose to manage the dependencies yourself and you now have incpoatible versions. Instead you should be using the different Spring Boot starters (or the dependency management at least) to get proper version.

Comment: Unfortunately, the spring-integration-kafka version is currently not managed by boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 3.1.5 with Boot 2.1.x - the latest 3.1.x, and 3.2.1 with Boot 2.2.x - see the [compatibility matrix here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka).

Spring Integration Kafka is still an extension and its version is not managed by boot because it has a faster release cadence.

It will be pulled into the main project "soon".

Comment: Russel i tried above with spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and encountered same error. MVN tree :- 

mvn dependency:tree | find "kafka"
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:jar:3.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile

Comment: Don't put stuff like that in coments; it's too hard to read. Edit the question to show your complete POM.

Comment: That POM works fine for me; no errors; even with the really old Boot 2.1.3 (over a year); the current 2.1.x version is 2.1.13.

Comment: maven clean install is working fine even for me, the issue is when i run this spring boot application i get above error.

Comment: I tested your POM with an existing boot program that I have and it runs just fine; there must be something wrong with your runtime class path.

Comment: Thanks Gary, It was Kafka ContainerProperties that i was referencing in config xml has incorrect package detail. The version you suggested has worked.